# Definition of the strong Diffie Hellman problem

Tags: diffie-hellman, hardness-assumptions

I am looking for the definition of the strong Diffie Hellmann problem. However, I can only find definitions for the $\ell$ or $q$-strong Diffie Hellmann.

Is it possible that the strong Diffie Hellman problem is also called the $\ell$ or $q$-strong Diffie Hellmann problem?

Comment: @Ievgeni: Excuse me, I would like to ask whether the strength of q-SDH is related to q? Can q be 0 or 1? Just like this: input $g \in G, g' \in G',(g,(g')^a)$, output $(g^{\frac{1}{a+s}},s)$, Does it belong to q-SDH？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/221.pdf) (page 6), the $q$-Strong Diffie-Hellman problem (or just Strong Diffie-Hellman problem in short) is the following one:
In a bilinear context $(\mathbb{G}_1, \mathbb{G}_2, \mathbb{G}_T)$.

Let $g_1$ and $g_2$ be public generators of $\mathbb{G}_1$, and $\mathbb{G}_2$.

The adversary receives: $\left(g^{x^i}_1\right)^q_{i=0}$ and $g_2, g_2^x$, with $x$ a random secret scalar, and should output a pair $\left(c, g^{\frac{1}{x+c}}\right)$ with $c$ a scalar of his choice.

Comment: 2K, congratulations. Now your edits are free :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and source!

Comment: The link for the pdf doesn't work. Do you have an alternative link or the title/author of the papers?

Comment: @user93353 I've changed the link

Comment: Thank you .....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the $\ell$ or $q$ is related to the parametrization, since the basic idea is to give you a number of known values and ask you to compute a related quantity and consider the hardness of this problem. For example, a Eurocrypt 2006 paper by Cheon available [here](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2006/40040001/40040001.pdf) states:

> Given $g$ and $g^{\alpha^i}$ in an abelian group $G$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,\ell$
> compute $g^{\alpha^{\ell+1}}.$ Here $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p.$

It was first introduced by Boneh and
Boyen to construct a short signature scheme, that is provably secure in
the standard model (without random oracles).

Comment: Can you give a source about your definition?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!